# Vue3 (Composition API) integration with HereMaps Polygon API Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, heremaps, here-maps-rest

In my vue3 application I was trying to integrate HereMaps, The map is loading fine and display map correctly, but when I try to draw a polygon using below code (same from the HereMap documentation) the map container become blank and browser ran into below error. The same code was working fine with vue2. Any help in resolving the issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
const lineString = new H.geo.LineString(
      [52, 13, 100, 48, 2, 100, 48, 16, 100, 52, 13, 100],
      'values lat lng alt'
    )
    map.value.addObject(
      new H.map.Polygon(lineString, {
        style: {
          fillColor: '#FFFFCC',
          strokeColor: '#829',
          lineWidth: 8,
        },
      })
    )
```

[image]

Comment: The question cannot be answered. What you may find out about this error is that it's obscure and may appear under random circumstances. It's very specific to your case and probably your system or browser. Please, provide a way to reproduce it and make sure this can be done on other machines